# What's the difference between -webkit-linear-gradient and linear-gradient?

Tags: css, webkit, gradient

How to convert
`-webkit-linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);`
to
`linear-gradient()`?

When I tried `linear-gradient(65deg,#A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);` it's giving completely different display.

Comment: add 45deg to the angle

Comment: also -webkit-linear-gradient is obsolete since tooo long so you should no more use it

Comment: @TemaniAfif 1. This is not the solution. The formula is `angle = -(wkAngle - 90)`. 2. That is probably the reason why this question is asked.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between `-webkit-linear-gradient()` and `linear-gradient()` is that `linear-gradient()` assumes `0 deg` when gradient is applied from bottom to top but `-webkit-linear-gradient()` assumes `0 deg` when gradient is applied from left to right.

Also `linear-gradient()` assumes deg in clockwise direction but `-webkit-linear-gradient()` assumes deg in anti clockwise direction.

Comment: The Formula is: `angle = -(wkAngle - 90)`